# How to check if one C++ class extends another (like if that another one was an interface)?

Tags: c++, oop, interface, extension-methods

So generally having

```
class A { ... };
class B { ... };
class C: public A, public B {};  // C inherits from A and B.
```

when we create an instance of C and want to pass it into some function ho do we check if class we pass to a function is extending A?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`C` is defined as inheriting from `A` so there is no need to check:

It is mandatory that an instance of `C` is also a `A` (and a `B`).

However, if you have a function taking a `A` as a parameter, you can use `dynamic_cast<>` to check if the instance is actually a `C`:

```
void function(const A& a)
{
  const C* c = dynamic_cast<const C*>(&a);

  if (c)
  {
    // a is an instance of C and you can use c to call methods of C
  } else
  {
    // a is not an instance of C.
  }
}
```

For this to work, however, the base class type must be *polymorphic* (it must have at least a virtual method).

Comment: I ran `const C* c = dynamic_cast<const C*>(&a)` but it gave me `error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘& a’ (of type ‘class A*’) to type ‘const class C*’ (source type is not polymorphic)`

Comment: @BarneyHsiao: I updated the answer to explain why you get this error. In a nutshell, the base class must have at least one virtual method (it may be the destructor) if you want to use `dynamic_cast<>` on it.

Answer (score 3):

The only time you'd need to do this is during compile time since implicit conversion works everywhere else.  But if you want to see if some type T is a base of some type S then you can use SFINAE (or just use is_base_of<>):

```
template < typename T, typename S >
struct is_base_of // checks if T is a base of S
{
  typedef char (yes&) [1];
  typedef char (no&)  [2];

  void yes check(T*);
  void no  check(...);

  enum { value = sizeof(check(static_cast<S*>(0))) == sizeof(yes); }
};
```