# Class within class - incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Publicatie{
public:
    class Carte : public Publicatie{
    private:
        char* autor;
    };
    class Revista : public Publicatie{
    private:
        char* frecventa_aparitie;
        int numar;
    };
private:
    int cota;
    char* titlu;
    char* editura;
    int anul_aparitiei;
    int tiraj;
    Carte* c;
    Revista* r;
        public:
           //some methods...
}
```

This is the code, i'm declaring the class Carte and Revista inside the class Publicatie and i need to have private members Carte and Publicatie. I really don't know how to do the design with inheritance with these classes. I get the error in the title for the inheritance :public Publicatie and i thought that it will work because the class is already created ( even though it's private members were not created yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your design is wrong. you're trying to define a class, and in it's definition you're trying to use from itself; it is a logical paradox.
from what i can understand from your code, you're trying to create a class named `Publicatie` that represents a publication (or a post) and it has two other variants, named `Carte` and `Revista`. if this is the case, why the `Publicatie` needs to have two private members of type `Carte` and `Revista`? maybe you can remove these two members from it.
or maybe you can move some of their shared members (such as `titlu`, `tiraj` and...) to another class that is abstract, and then define `Publicatie`, `Carte` and `Revista` such that all of them inherit from the same parent class.
hope these work.

Comment: Indeed, this is correct, thank you :) I know it was a bad design i just couldn't figure out the correct one.

Comment: Specifically the Publication (publicatie) class should have inside 2 specifiers Book (carte) if the publication is a book or Magazine (Revista) if it is a magazine. I thought this is the correct way to design the principle. Could you suggest a better one ?

Comment: i think the best way is not including `Carte` and `Revista` in `Publicatie`. instead, inherit both of them from `Publicatie` and add the needed members or methods (like `numar`) to them. then everywhere in your code that a function takes a `Publicatie` as an argument, check to see if it is a `Cartie` or a `Revista` or none of them, using `dynamic_cast`. to see how to do this, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4704988/663036). also, this solution only works if you have virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can only inherit from a class that is a complete type. However, you don't need to have the nested class definition inside your ambient class definition. Instead, you can do it like so:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar;

    Bar * p;

    int get();
};

struct Foo::Bar : Foo
{
    int zip() { return 4; }
};

int Foo::get() { return p->zip(); }
```

Comment: Does this have a valid semantic meaning? Inner class inheriting from the outer one sounds like a bad mix of composition and inheritance.

Comment: @icepack: It means what it means... it's a bit recursive, yes, like a "linked list" of inheritance. I didn't say it was a good idea :-)